# How do I safely use select with a PyOpenSSL connection object?

Tags: python, pyopenssl

Python: 2.7.2 on Windows Vista
Egenix PyOpenSSL: 0.13.0

I am attempting to write a proxy service.  Basically, the proxy service listens on a regular socket and an SSL socket, relaying data between the two.

I am able to semi-reliable relay data, but when the server on the other end of the SSL socket is done sending data, I get a spurious signal that there is more data available to be read.  The code basically looks like this:

```
(rs, ws, xs) = select.select([client, sslserver], [], [])
for r in rs:
    if r == client:
        # tons of client code
    elif r == sslserver:
        (rs, ws, xs) = select.select([sslserver], [], [], 0)
        print 'Reading server: %s, %s' % (len(rs), server.pending())
        while len(rs) > 0 or sslserver.pending() > 0:
            t = sslserver.read(sslserver.pending())
            # Do more useful stuff
            (rs, ws, xs) = select.select([sslserver], [], [], 0)
```

With this code, I see the text `Reading server: 1, 0` sometimes before going into the read block.  When I actually execute `t = sslserver.read(sslserver.pending())`, the result is a toss-up.  I frequently get an EOF exception (SSL.SysCallError()[1] == 'Unexpected EOF').  The problem is that sometimes this is a true EOF, and sometimes SSL just hasn't made any data available.

But, if I change the read line to read like this

```
t = sslserver.read(4096)
```

as is my wont in most socket reading code, instead of getting anything to indicate EOF (which a regular socket would!  select says that the socket is ready for reading.  There is no data to be read.  So immediately return no data!), my code just blocks when there is no data left to be read.  This makes no sense, of course.  After all, the socket is ready for reading.  It should just block until the EOF gets through the decryption phase.

But it doesn't.  It's a permanent block.

What are my options?  I absolutely believe now that select.select is not safe with a PyOpenSSL socket.  Is there some other way to monitor an SSL socket with a regular socket, or am I going to need to move the SSL socket into a separate thread and use a normal socket to relay data into my main thread?